# TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM support

Tags: java, encryption

I am getting below error when trying to run a server with TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported CipherSuite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.validValuesOf(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(Unknown Source)
at org.dcm4che3.net.TCPListener.createTLSServerSocket(TCPListener.java:87)
at org.dcm4che3.net.TCPListener.(TCPListener.java:67)
at org.dcm4che3.net.Connection.bind(Connection.java:976)
at org.dcm4che3.net.Device.bindConnections(Device.java:746)
at org.dcm4che3.tool.storescp.StoreSCP.main(StoreSCP.java:288)

Is there a workaround or fix for the same?

Comment: (1) if you don't actually need that (unusual and rare) ciphersuite, change your config and/or code to not use it (2) if you do, use BouncyCastle (bctls) instead -- assuming dcm4che3, whatever that is, doesn't otherwise depend on features (or misfeatures) specific to standard JSSE

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Does that mean standard java does not support that cipher suite and so we depend on BouncyCastle? dcm4che is a suite of tools that are used for Medical Device testing. dcm4che could have dependency with standard java, I have very limited knowledge on the same.

Comment: Yes, 'standard' Java -- more exactly, the SunJSSE provider packaged with Oracle Java and OpenJDK -- does not support any CCM ciphersuites, so if you really need it/them BouncyCastle is the only way I know to do so in Java. There _may_ be other thirdparty TLS providers for Java I don't know about. Another option would be to terminate TLS _outside_ of Java, with something like nginx or haproxy or stunnel which can support any suite(s) you like and forward to Java, but that might involve changes to your software I can't estimate.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Oh, is it? Thanks for the info. I was under the impression that standard java (Oracle) supports them as I could see CCM mentioned in the below links: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.htm#JSSEC-GUID-63945B45-E909-483F-B3A9-E26586737383 and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html

Comment: 'Standard Names' are the names to be used IF certain things are implemented; for what is ACTUALLY implemented by a provider see that PROVIDER's documentation, with the newest at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-7093246A-31A3-4304-AC5F-5FB6400405E2 . (You do know 10 is no longer supported, right?)

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 Do you know how to configure the provider to Bouncy Castle? I tried adding this in java.security file, but there was no change in behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Dave, standard java does not support CCM. We need to use Bouncy Castle.